# UICollectionView subclass override selection method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have an `UICollectionView` subclass where I want to do something if a cell gets selected.

The collectionView subclass supports drag-selection. If a long press is detected, the view turns on multiple selection mode to select multiple cells.

I now want to disable multiple selection mode again. But, obviously, when disabling multiple selection, the selection gets deleted.

I now want to put myself in between of the internal implementation to get notified when my own selection will change. I would then disable multiple selection.

I also wouldn't like to do this via the delegate view controller, because I plan to make a reusable class for multiple projects.

So how can I get notified of selection changes in my subclass? Is there any property I could use for KVO?

Answer (score 0):

how about do the selection changing in the delegate of UICollectionView
there is a method `-didSelect...` when `-didSelect` invoked, deselect the old cell